Multiprocessing on Python Jupyter Notebook with one function
I am implementing an algorithm that has a high execution time and I need to use all the cpu power for a part of the code that involves heavy processing. I have written it in the form of a function, but I have encountered problems in executing it as a multiprocessing.
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
shape = (len(ta52))
g5 = np.zeros(shape)
shape = (5,len(ta52))
g6 = np.zeros(shape)
m=0
def test(ta52):
    m=0
    for i in ta52:
        s11=[]
        for j in s1:
            s11.append(sum(c1!=c2 for c1,c2 in zip(i,j)))
        s12=[]
        for j in s2:
            s12.append(sum(c1!=c2 for c1,c2 in zip(i,j)))
        s13=[]
        for j in s3:
            s13.append(sum(c1!=c2 for c1,c2 in zip(i,j)))
        s14=[]
        for j in s4:
            s14.append(sum(c1!=c2 for c1,c2 in zip(i,j)))
        s15=[]
        for j in s5:
            s15.append(sum(c1!=c2 for c1,c2 in zip(i,j)))
        sp=min(s11)+min(s12)+min(s13)+min(s14)+min(s15)
        g5[m]=sp
        g6[0,m]=min(s11)
        g6[1,m]=min(s12)
        g6[2,m]=min(s13)
        g6[3,m]=min(s14)
        g6[4,m]=min(s15)
        m=m+1
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Process(target=test)
    p.start()
    print('Waiting for mp_func to end')
    p.join()
#print(g5)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start) 

and result is:
Waiting for mp_func to end
Time:  0.17289580000000626
But my test function doesn't run.

You're not providing any arguments to your target function, but it requires one positional argument (ta52).
Your example won't run at all, because shape = (len(ta52)) references an unbound variable, ta52, so I'm wondering how you get a printout at all.
The same is true for the last two lines, where you reference the start variable, which is also not defined.
Perhaps something is missing in the example?
If ta52 was defined, you would do the following:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Process(target=test, args=(ta52,))  # Add argument here
    p.start()
    print('Waiting for mp_func to end')
    p.join()

Also note that your implementation would in fact slow the code down, as you're only running one function in one process. So you're spending time spawning a new process, but not actually running anything in parallel. Maybe that part was cut out to make the example smaller?
Finally, the title indicates that you're running the code in a notebook. In that case, the if __name__ == "__main__" isn't needed at all and I doubt if __name__ actually defined in notebooks in the same way that it is for regular Python-interpreted files.
